# Yii2 check database changes

Tags: php, jquery, database, yii2

Today I ran into a problem with Yii2. I have a database with a list of numbers. These numbers are attached to clients. Every 5 senconds I update the page with jQuery to get the new records. My problem is that I only want do a notification when a new record arrives not every refresh (5 seconds)

Is there a solution to check if the database changed in Yii or should I do it in the client side?

Here is the controller method:

```
$behivott = Sorszam::find()->with('ablak')
            ->orderBy(['behivas_datum' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(1)
            ->all();
        $sorszamok = Sorszam::find()->with('ablak')
            ->orderBy(['behivas_datum' => SORT_DESC])
            ->andWhere(['>', 'behivas_datum', 'nyomtatas_datum'])
            ->limit(4)
            ->offset(1)
            ->all();

        $reklam = Reklam::find()->all();
        return $this->render('generatePage', [
            'sorszamok' => $sorszamok,
            'reklam'    => $reklam,
            'behivott'  => $behivott,
        ]);
```

Thank your for your answers!

Gábor

Comment: you will need something else to do that like websokets

Comment: Oh, i see. I was thinking that if i create a function in php that checks the database and if it changes i do the notif. The question is that PHP can handle this. Or should i put the number's data into some kind of temporary place?

Comment: see websoket documentation

Comment: I suppose you could add a 'modified' timestamp to your database table, and then your AJAX polling could request only data that changed after the previous request.

Comment: I started with websockets now but yes @Thernys this is what i needed. Thank you madalin ivascu as well!

Comment: If the numbers are always increasing, you could use a count() on that table and compare it to the previous (you can send it via jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not poissible to do it server side with PHP.

The best you could do if you dont want to use AJAX is using websockets.

With websockets you can trigger an action in real time.

Comment: I created an application in NodeJs where i can run queries then installed Socket.io (really great package btw.). Actually is there any event based aproach of it. I mean for example onChange event where the code can  monitor the database changes?

Comment: No, when you change something in your database you have to send a trigger to your websocket server with data and check for changes on your client side